# synthesizer error in java

Tags: java, swing, text-to-speech, synthesizer

First time App work fine.But when I click "Speech" button for second time It make errors

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:684)
at com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSSynthesizer.handleAllocate(FreeTTSSynthesizer.java:98)
at com.sun.speech.engine.BaseEngine.allocate(BaseEngine.java:219)
at text2speech.GUI.speechFile(GUI.java:141)
at text2speech.GUI.jButton2ActionPerformed(GUI.java:159)
at text2speech.GUI.access$100(GUI.java:24)
at text2speech.GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:61)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is the code.

```
public void speechFile(){

String context=jTextArea1.getText();
        try
 {
   System.setProperty("freetts.voices","com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");

   Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
   Synthesizer  synthesizer =Central.createSynthesizer(new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.US));
   synthesizer.allocate();
   synthesizer.resume();
   synthesizer.speakPlainText(context, null);
   synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
   synthesizer.deallocate();
  }
   catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }    catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AudioException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (EngineException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The thing I don't understand is first it work fine.second time it makes errors.How to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about this library or technique, but to me it seems odd that you would register the engine once for each use, and odd that you wouldn't reuse an existing synthesizer.

Have you tried creating the synthesizer once and using it twice?

Answer (score 1):

to make the code read more than once, all you have to do to remove the synth.deallocate(); from your code, then you will be able to loop till you want.